# How to close a pop up without exiting the main program

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I am a beginner in Android app development, and I have a problem with an old app. I have to close an activity that is open over another activity: for example, a pop up that is open on top of the main app. How I close the popup and return false without exiting the main program, using the mobilePhone button `onBackPressed()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onBackPressed` method like this:

```
 public void onBackPressed(){

    // If you have a reference to the other activity.
    popupActivity.finish();
 }
```